# Is there a way to read a properties file from tomcat into react?

Tags: reactjs, tomcat, properties-file

I am trying to parse data from a `.properties` file from my tomcat/conf folder into my front end React project. This data will be used to populate fields & dropdowns.

Example of what `.properties` file contains:

```
ABCD1234=ABCD1234,org.exampleco.goat._0_1.mx19.MX19,org.exampleco.goat._0_1.pingpong.LCM1
```

The contents of this file will change in different environments. Is there something that converts `.properties` to JSON? How do I even call the file in tomcat, because my local file path might be different than it is in other environments.

Comment: There is a Java system property `catalina.base`, which contains the path to Tomcat's installation directory (`CATALINA_BASE` to be exact). How you want to transform it into JSON is up to you: please provide an example of transformation in your question.

Comment: A properties file is a key/value file.  A JSON object may or may not be the same.  You'll need to write code to read the properties file (see the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html) for details) and send it out as a JSON object that you define.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz and @stdunbar thanks for your comments. Really helped me a lot. The application has 2 different repos, one for back end and the other for front end. I can see where the data is being read in the back end repo. Now I need to figure out how to get the backend to communicate with the front end.

The end goal is to get a dropdown displaying the values like this...
`<Select value={type ? type : ""}  onChange={handleChange}>
 {menu.map((item) => <MenuItem value={item.value}>{item.value}</MenuItem>}
</Select>`

Comment: I wound up resolving the issue. I had to make new API calls in the front end repo. Thank you both for pointing me in the right direction.